# CSS: how align to top nth row of div?

Tags: css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5qdZr/

I want that the first div containing a photo of the second row be "aligned to top" to the first div containing a photo of the first row, and the third div containing a photo of the second row must be "aligned to top" with the third div containing a photo of the first row.

Aligned to top of course with 5px margin set in css (#gallery div.placeholder)

html:

```
<div id="gallery">
<div class="placeholder">
<a href="#" title="" data-gallery="">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
</a>
[... repeat so on]
</div>
```

css:

```
#gallery{background-color:red;}
#gallery img{-webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;-moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;-ms-transition: opacity 0.4s;transition: opacity 0.4s;width:100%;}
#gallery div.placeholder{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:30%;margin:5px;}
```

PRE: [image]

I NEED THIS: [image]

Comment: wow, perhaps a picture of the desired output would help here :)

Comment: add this in css img{max-height: 120px;}

Comment: sorry, this makes no sense

Comment: @MahmoudeElghandour : it is not what i need...

Comment: @ZatrhusWriter : added photo! :)

Comment: What you need is columns.

Comment: This is typical situation where you should use professional **css grids** or **jquery grids**. Google it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple, foolproof, CSS-only way of doing this for a general case.

Most people who achieve similar layouts use a JavaScript/jQuery plug-in/library such as:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Alternatively, you need to create a 3-column layout either using a grid framework like Bootstrap or a HTML table (or `display: table`).

Comment: Unfortunately i have many problems in IE8. Masonry, great plugin, seems doesn't work on IE8

Comment: Supporting IE8 is a major constraint and you should make that clear in your original post.  You might want to consider my alternative idea of setting up a three column layout and distributing your images accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could float:left placeholder.

But it won't give you exact result you want.

I think you need to use a bit of javascript to absolutely position the elements.

or adjust margins (negative margin-tops)

Answer (score 0):

the html code has to be the same like yours? the problem here is your `display:inline-block` and the order of the divs.

if only the result is important and not the given code structure i would change it to this:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aS5W7/1/)

hope it helps